# PHP `file_get_contents()` output pass to JavaScript and calculate length

Tags: javascript, php

I want to pass the output from PHP's `file_get_contents()` to JavaScript and calculate its length. Everything ok but when passing the variable JavaScript evaluates it as HTML code, so I have to use PHP's `json_encode()` to keep it "sane" but this way the string length from JavaScript will be different from the one in PHP. Using JS's `JSON.parse()` doesn't help because again the HTML code gets interpreted. Any idea how can I achieve the same evaluated data length?

EDIT: Basically I need to count all the characters in the page source, that includes tags and special characters. To have the same output computed in JS like the one i get in PHP's `strlen($url_data)`.

EDIT 2: I thought about doing `bin2hex()` on the `$url_data` then reconvert in JS and check the length. Would be that reliable?

Here is what I did so far:

```
<?php

ini_set('display_erros', -1);

$error = '';

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    if (isset($_POST['urlinput']) && !filter_var($_POST['urlinput'], FILTER_VALIDATE_URL) === false) {
        $url = filter_var($_POST['urlinput'], FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
        $url_data = @file_get_contents($url);
        $js_url_data = json_encode($url_data);
        //$url_src = htmlspecialchars($url, ENT_IGNORE);
        $url_data_len = mb_strlen($url_data);
        $url_src = strip_tags($url_data);
        echo '<ul id="resultList">';
        echo "<li>The following page contains " . $url_data_len . " characters</li>";
        echo "<li>Page URL: " . $_POST['urlinput'] . "</li>";
        echo "<li>Page title: " . page_title($url_data) . "</li>";
        echo "<li>Protocol: " . parse_url($url, PHP_URL_SCHEME) . "</li>";
        echo "<li>Host: " . parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST) . "</li>";
        echo "</ul>";
        //var_dump($url_src);
    } else {
        $error = "URL is not valid!";
    }

}

function page_title($str) {

    $matches = array();

    if (preg_match('/<title>(.*?)<\/title>/i', $str, $matches)) {
        return $matches[1];
    }
    else {
        return null;
    }
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>PHP file_get_contents()</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="url_class">
        <form id="getsrc" method="post">
            <input style="width: 300px;" type="text" name="urlinput" id="urlinput" placeholder="URL">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Get SRC">
        </form>
    </div>
    <textarea rows="20" cols="50">
<?php
if (!empty($url_src)) {
    echo $url_src;
}
?>
    </textarea>
    <?php echo '<br><span style="color:red">' . $error . '<span>'; ?>
<?php
if (!empty($js_url_data)) {
$script = <<<EOT
<script>
    var url_data = $js_url_data;
    var node = document.createElement("li");
    var textnode = document.createTextNode("JavaScript page characters: " + url_data.length);
    node.appendChild(textnode);
    document.getElementById("resultList").appendChild(node);
</script>
EOT;
echo $script;
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: json_encode() is designed to encode PHP array or object structure, but not to perform xml/html operation...

Comment: I know, but couldn't think about other method to pass a "sanitized" html data to javaScript. Any idea?

Comment: what do you mean by sanitized : escaped or encoded HTML Tags ? html tags should be computed for the length of total string ? what do you want to achieve is not very clear for me and maybe you will get approximatives answers... i think if you add an example that illustrates you goal can help much more :)

Comment: Basically I need to count all the characters in the page source, that includes tags and special characters. To have the same output computed in JS like the one i get in PHP's `strlen($url_data)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since no good answer, I would post my solution to my problem. The only way I could find was to hex-encode `$url_data`, pass it to JS, decode it and count the characters. For the `pack()` function I used the one ported in `php.js`.

```
...
$js_url_data = bin2hex($url_data);
...
if (!empty($js_url_data)) {
/* This is a good example when one is forced to use inline JS */
$script = <<<EOT
<script>
    var url_data = "$js_url_data";
    var url_data_len = pack('H*', url_data).length;
    var node = document.createElement("li");
    var textnode = document.createTextNode("JavaScript calculation page characters: " + url_data_len);
    node.appendChild(textnode);
    document.getElementById("resultList").appendChild(node);
</script>
EOT;
echo $script;
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the value calculated by php, it can be used within EOT block:

```
...
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
if (isset($_POST['urlinput']) && !filter_var($_POST['urlinput'], FILTER_VALIDATE_URL) === false) {
  ...
  $url_data = @file_get_contents($url);
  $fileSize = strlen($url_data);
  ...
}
....

if (!empty($js_url_data)) {
$script = <<<EOT
<script>
  ...
  var textnode = document.createTextNode("JavaScript page characters: " + $fileSize);
  ...
</script>
EOT;
```

echo $script;

Comment: This is simple, I know. The problem is I need to use the value of JS's `data.length` not PHP calculation.